# For WSS (Windows Storage Server) 2016, does unlimited CALs mean unlimited concurrent RDP active sessions?

Tags: remote-desktop, license, windows-server, windows-server-2016, windows-storage-server

For usual Windows Servers, there is a limit of 2 accounts being logged in and in active use simultaneously from remote desktop or the terminal - and more concurrent account users require proportionally more CALs. For Windows Storage Server 2016 - since they advertise as unlimited CALs, does that mean any number of accounts can actively be logged in and in active use simultaneously?

Comment: Number of CALs have never meant number of allowed concurrent connections. The latter is a technical matter. CALs simply say how many licenses you have.

Comment: Then I revise the question to be how many concurrent RDP sessions as usually WS lets 2 (https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln163689/windows-server-an-overview-of-windows-remote-desktop-services-licensing?lang=en)

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Storage Server](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/storageserver/2016/10/14/announcing-windows-storage-server-2016/) does not even have Remote Desktop services. So this is a moot point.

Whatever licensing you are referring to does NOT refer to Remote Desktop.

With that said, Microsoft has different kinds of CALs. It could be a user CAL or device CAL for any number of different services: Windows Server; Remote Desktop services; Exchange; etc. Being this is a Windows storage server, the CALs you are referring to are clearly in regards to the number of users who can use file services.

Comment: Is this incorrect:
https://nascompares.com/guide/how-to-access-wss-storage-nas-server-with-remote-desktop/

Comment: @user3645994 having “Remote Desktop services” and having access via Remote Desktop is two different things. All windows servers have access via Remote Desktop for administrative purposes with up to two simultaneous connections. Remote Desktop services is something different. CALs aren’t required to connect to your server through RDP for administrative purposes. Your post is confusing the purpose of the “limit of 2 accounts” and the purpose requiring “proportionally more CALs,” and misunderstanding the differences between what services different CALs apply to. RDS is a server role.